# how to remove form feed from string in python

Tags: python, string, ascii, whitespace

I have a text file that contains the following:

```
'\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'
```

As you see it's all form feed characters, which I want to have removed.

I have tried various solutions but for some reason they don't seem to work.
For example, what I have tried is to remove the left `'\x0c`, the right `\x0c'`, and all the other `\x0c`, but the output remains the same.
The code is use:

```
import re
import string

with open('AF-40-A-00020539.txt', "r", encoding="ascii") as input_file:
    input_content = input_file.read()
    print(
        input_content.lstrip('\'\x0c')\
            .rstrip('\x0c\'')\
            .strip('\x0c')
            .replace('\x0c', '')
    )
```

After executing this, I get this as output `\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'` so not what I would expect.

What is the reason for this? How can I remove the form feed characters?

**UPDATE, thanks to joao's answer:**
\xHH, where HH are two hex digits, is a [recognised escape sequence](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html) to write ASCII characters using their [corresponding hex value](https://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html), just like \n is for a newline.

The `.replace('\x0c', '')` did not work because in this string literal `\xOc` got escaped, whereas in the text file, it was just copied as plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an ambiguity here: when you say the file contains `\x0c`, is that a single character in the file, displayed with the escape sequence that represents the hex value `0x0c` ? Or is it really a 4-character string ? You should try to determine that with a binary editor, or the `len()` function.

I suspect the 2nd case, because you say that you get `\x0c` as output. If it were the 1st case, you'd see `^L`, or a blank line, or some gibberish indicating a non-printable character.

If it's a single character, then

```
s = s.replace('\x0c', '')
```

will remove them. If they're really 4 characters, then

```
s = s.replace('\\x0c', '')
```

should work. Note the extra backslash `\` that turns an escape sequence into a 4-character string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but try this in .replace:

```
line.replace('\x0C', '')
```

Let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub()`:

```py
import re
string = "Hello, '\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'World!"
print(re.sub(r"'(\x0c)+'", '', string))
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
```